# When is every submodule of a module a direct sum of indecomposable submodules?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, ac.commutative-algebra, modules

Is there any reference for modules over a commutative ring with identity such that every submodule of them is a direct sum of indecomposable submodules? Or is there any characterization of such modules?